# How can I write tests in one Eclipse project for classes from another Eclipse project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing

I want to be able to have two projects, one that contains production code and one that contains test code.

This shouldn't necessarily be an Android-specific question, but I'm want to write some unit tests for some non-platform-specific Android code on the host PC.

I created a new Java project so I can run the unit tests on the PC and only include the non-platform-specific classes from the Android project.  Both projects are opened in the same Eclipse workspace.

I assume I need to somehow include these Android-project sources explicitly in the new project where I'll run the Junit tests, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) goto configure build path on the test project
2) in that dialog you will see a "tab" for "projects", click it
3) add the dependent project and click apply
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the project that contains the production code to the build path of the testing project then I imagine that should work. You can do this by right-clicking the testing project and selecting 'Build Path' > 'Configure Build Path', then going to the Projects tab and adding the production project.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand what your intent is, but I believe there is exactly this feature for Android Development.

Using the Android Development Tools (ADT) for Eclipse, you should be able to create a new project of type "Android Test Project". You define the project, but also choose your existing project for the Test Target.

The test project will have special privileges when run in an emulator or on a device. It will be able to access all parts of the application as it will run in the same security context.

Also, have a look at [Hello, Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html). Android provides quite a few testing utilities to get you started and save you from writing extra code.

Comment: Thanks Mark, however I am asking about testing non-Android-specific components that live within my Android project.  I want to test these components not on the device or even within the software emulator because both of these methods are prohibitively slow.

Comment: The Hello Testing link now gives a 404